# mysqli query make array out of names

Tags: php, mysqli

pretty sure this is something easy but i cant figure it out, basicly making a easy query like this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT t.name FROM cups_participants cp
              LEFT JOIN teams t on cp.team_id  = t.team_id
              WHERE cp.cup_id = '1'");
```

the above query should get all the names out of the database, now i want it to be put into array like this:

```
$competitors = array(
 'Paul A.M. Dirac', 
 'Hans Christian Oersted', 
 'Murray Gell-Mann', 
 'Marie Curie', 
 'Neils Bohr', 
 'Richard P. Feynman', 
 'Max Planck');
```

how do i get the result from my query into a array like the above on?

Comment: Surely you tried some approach already?

Comment: -1 http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: i did try it but i couldnt get it to work, im not a php programmer. i know the basic stuff and i wanna learn and since i personally learn way more from reading a example given i thought id just ask here. nice to see i get downvoted and get "dick" comments straight away for not knowing.. oww well..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$competitors = array();

$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT t.name FROM cups_participants cp
          LEFT JOIN teams t on cp.team_id  = t.team_id
          WHERE cp.cup_id = '1'");

if($result->num_rows > 0)
{
    while($rs = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
       $competitors[]=$rs['name'];
    }
}

echo "<pre />";
print_r($competitors);
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense why are you being such a dick? he gives me a working example and all you do is dick on people. pretty pathetic tbh